# matplotlib: Displaying an image as separate convolution regions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display an image using matplotlib. However I want to display said image as a series of subplots where each subplot represents a region which is used when performing valid convolution. So for example, the image in the first link is a 32x32 grayscale image. I want to perform convolution on this image using a 5x5 filter. So in order to see what the filter is being convolved with each time I want to split the image into separate overlapping 5x5 regions. The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
fig14 = plt.figure(14)
A = images[4,0,:,:]
for i in range(images.shape[3]-5+1): #counts from 0 to 27 (28 = no of convolutions)
    for j in range(images.shape[3]-5+1): #counts from 0 to 27
       plt.subplot(28,28,(i*28)+j+1)
       plt.gray
       plt.axis("off")
       plt.imshow(A[i:(i-1)+5,j:(j-1)+5])
```

The result is in the second link. I don't understand why there are completely black pixels in the centre? Surely they should all be white. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

[input image](http://s1299.photobucket.com/user/richardhankinsfbr/media/figure_1_zps57ssqf4d.png.html)

[result](http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag61/richardhankinsfbr/figure_14_zpsu2aupbg3.png)

Comment: They look all black because they are all one value (the "white" value), and each image is self-scaling.  You should set the vmin and vmax keywords to make all the sub-images the on same grayscale.

Comment: Thanks @Ajean. How would i go about doing that?

Comment: ..... as I said, vmin and vmax.  The documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) is very helpful.